# Tomcat DataSource getConnection working but throwing exceptions in log

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, datasource

Hi guys i am new to J2EE(but not java) and i am facing one problem with tomcat and java datasource. 
The Problem is when i call datasouce.getConnection() the server log  gets filled with exception however the app works fine (its able to fetch data from db)

my context.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/thmstordb" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="myuser" password="mypass"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/themestore?profileSQL=true"
        maxTotal="10" maxIdle="4" />
 
</Context>
```

my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>ThemeStore</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>themestore-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
         </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>com.mmx.services</param-value>
  </init-param>
   <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>themestore-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/thmstordb</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

exceptions:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71OH33lwaXwcUZLTTBPdFpxeFk/view?usp=sharing

Can someone help me what i can do to eliminate these exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried removing `profileSQL=true` from connection string? Maybe this bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70677 causes the problem.

Comment: it worked thanks! :) you can post it as answer i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the sake of completeness (because it seems to work):*

Have you tried removing `profileSQL=true` from connection string? Maybe this bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70677 causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the exceptions stopped coming once i removed ProfileSQL=true from my jdbc url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/themestore?profileSQL=true"